# How to use different colors for two rectangle and how to set distance between those two rectangles to zero?

Tags: colors, alignment, plantuml

- I tried to give each rectangle a different color but unfortunately it did not work
- I want the horizontal distance between those two rectangles to be zero

Here is what I want:

[image: target]

And here is the code and result: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/rP9FIyD04CNl-ocMUXEAIMn198PYeE1PZu9iacawT3CRPgSjMlpkhfiISoXuyEISNjuly-V1hhmObdrdbTyXzOPDfviUzI999exVciOTaLgzCTR3X5IcthNizjJKpZhMmePyG42YrEG_XbeCjHRqIUbGiQLqJC0wNKRhMO31oNiFQqTInd5NbGqB8hveFexhpsWTQs2E6-2pdoJBzAvKwZDSzNFBBFVu0VTPLhoWXEyql_asYbSQG5hacx1MnsmFnoqA54W7z5XPc1-01MjZvo5mZTIEpM-X_ZZYMZy9T3eTLJQgszdfjnpPlyWngiK5jHnIhe2Qy3g_0000

Comment: I don't see a different color in your image that you posted to show what you would like to have.

Comment: for left rectangle i want for example green color and for right rectangle i want be the same as foto or blue color

Comment: @albert but the most important thing to set the horizontal distance between these two rectangle to zero

Answer (score 0):

> but the most important thing to set the horizontal distance between these two rectangle to zero

It's not possible to do a 0 horizontal distance between two rectangles in PlantUML. You could do a table in Creole, but it won't look like your example, since the lines (rows) would be aligned in a table.

When I see your usage, I think you'd be better off using DOT (GraphViz). You can wrap DOT code in `@startdot`/`@enddot` in a PlantUML engine and it will draw the diagram. For example:

https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/TP1HIyCm58NVyol2_GDJvfj9MDkK8PIbn88FOm_PShN5q9OqeY3-TvDfApBMXzwSd2_dmDrCmVXWXq1iz-BDsD8f-BTJcEWdeV7h1ujqFxLcH3uwq_K1Fy8XMR_WckwTEQBZZB0cowkIvahBKdEu0LgKLJNBsn_vM6V5mswxs7KcvLdV0SstXQfKP7KfGSGIrkWqqa5IhPxYuns7DOWMdHjOhbVYVV3EibKZ_y0Oie37sOfJNqGkXMFNlu8udU5ar4et75hq2CBEjmAlX5tMFlydup-jHeZ3FVaY6-njtFWt

But, since you're writing lower-level DOT, you need to use that syntax to lay everything out. There is much more control, but it's no longer PlantUML.